# Why doesn't pointer arithmetic work in char* functions

Tags: c, string

THE MESSAGE:

```
/usr/local/webide/runners/c_runner.sh: line 54: 20533 Segmentation fault
nice -n 10 valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file="$valgrindout" "$exefile"
```

I can't understand why I can't use pointer arithmetic when my function type is not void. Take a look at this example:

Let's say I have to write a function that would 'erase' all whitespaces before the first word in a string. 
For example, if we had a char array:

```
"    Hi everyone"
```

it should produce `"Hi everyone"` after the function's modification.

Here is my code which works fine when instead of
`char* EraseWSbeforethefirstword()` I have
`void EraseWSbeforethefirstword`.

When the function returns an object `char*` it can't even be compiled.

```
char* EraseWSbeforethefirstword(char *s) {
    char *p = s, *q = s;

    if (*p == ' ') { /*first let's see if I have a string that begins with a space */
        while (*p == ' ') {
            p++;
        } /*moving forward to the first non-space character*/

        while (*p!= '\0') {
            *q = *p; 
            p++; 
            q++;
        } /*copying the text*/

        *q = '\0'; /*If I had n spaces at the beginning the new string has n characters less */
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Oh and, can you please format your code so it can be more easily readable...

Comment: Did you add a return statement in the code that didn't compile?

Comment: Your function changes `s` in place.  It seems like you want it to return something instead.  What do you want it to return? Please show us your code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Could you make a [mcve] and demonstrate what happens? Then explain what you do not like about it, i.e. show what you want as result.

Comment: If you declare a function differently than `void ....` then you need to have a `return ...;` at the end. But you are aware of that, are you not? So what is the compiler error you get if you "return an object char*" ?

Comment: Hi guys, I actually wanted to simply return s (the beginning of the string) but it doesn't work here is the version that does not work:
    char* EraseWSbeforethefirstword(char *s) {
char* p=s, *q=s; /* I have substitiutions for s */
if(*p==' ') { /* if the first character is space than I need to get to the first non-space character */
    while (*p==' ') {
         p++;
    }  /* q is still the beginning and p is the beginning of the word */
    while(*p!='\0') {*q=*p; p++; q++;} /*copying the text */
    *q='\0';  /*if I had n spaces newstring has n characters less */
} return s;
}

Comment: Please edit additionall information into your question instead of hiding it in a comment.

Comment: I am aware of that...I know I must have a "return" in a non-void function...but it doesn't work

Comment: Please, can you edit your first post? Reading a whole function in a comment is just terrible...

Comment: **How** does it not work? You know you are pretty close to being off-topic as a "why does my code not work" question without decent explanation...

Comment: I modified the code, sorry for waiting...thank you very much I hope I'll  solve this with you...

Comment: @Djule  There is operator !=. It is not the same as ! = (with an intermediate blank)

Comment: The lacking explanation is not how you think the code works, it is a description of the symptoms how it does **not** work. Quote the error message, describe the unwanted output in contrast to the desired output, maybe share your result of finding out where it crashes (if it does)...

Comment: I modified the first post and gave you explicit explanations what the code does...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The broken operator is by an edit, not by OP. I fixed it, thanks for finding.

Comment: Okay...just a second I'll give you the quote of the error

Comment: /usr/local/webide/runners/c_runner.sh: line 54: 20533 Segmentation fault      nice -n 10 valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file="$valgrindout" "$exefile"

Comment: Does it now work or not? If you cannot reproduce the error anymore, the question will get flagged and closed.

Comment: As @VladfromMoscow pointed out, I think you're calling your function with a pointer to a string literal somewhere, and that's wrong... I suggest you take a break, think about what you want *exactly*, search on the internet and come back to it.

Comment: @ZeusInTexas that's the problem...but the tests are made by an unprofessional bachelor student so...Thank you very much for helping me I hope I didn't bother you too much...

Comment: Well, here to help anyway so... it's fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function implementation that has the return type `char *` as you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *  EraseWSbeforethefirstword( char *s ) 
{
    if ( *s == ' ' || *s == '\t' )
    {
        char *p = s, *q = s;

        while ( *p == ' ' || *p == '\t' ) ++p;

        while ( ( *q++ = *p++ ) );
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "\t Hello World";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", EraseWSbeforethefirstword( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"    Hello World"
"Hello World"
```

Take into account that you may not modify string literals. So the program will have undefined behavior if instead of the array

```
char s[] = "\t Hello World";
```

there will be declared a pointer to a string literal

```
char *s = "\t Hello World";
```

If you want that the function could deal with string literals then the function has to allocate a new array dynamically and to return a pointer to its first element.

If you may not use standard C string functions then the function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *  EraseWSbeforethefirstword( const char *s )
{
    size_t blanks = 0;

    while ( s[blanks] == ' ' || s[blanks] == '\t' ) ++blanks;

    size_t length = 0;

    while ( s[length + blanks] != '\0' ) ++length;

    char *p = malloc( length + 1 );

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        while ( ( p[i] = s[i + blanks] ) != '\0' ) ++i;
    }

    return p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s= "\t Hello World";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    char *p = EraseWSbeforethefirstword( s );

    if ( p ) printf( "\"%s\"\n", p );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It says the problem is "*q='\0';" when I remove that command then it says the problem is the line "while(*p==' ')"...I know how to make the code more estetically acceptable...It says the problem is "while(*q++=*p++)" if I write write it instead of my three-four lines of code that do the same

Comment: @Djule As you see in my function implementation there are used two pairs of parentheses.

Comment: @Djule Or you can write instead while ( ( *q++ = *p++ ) != '\0' );

Comment: @Djule: Are you running into problems with CRLF line endings in your source code but compilation on a Unix machine, or something similar?  Your description of the problem moving as you move code around sounds like a problem with the editing of the source code more than anything else.  Showing the exact error message you're getting from the compiler would help enormously.  You'd need to show your best representation of the code and the error message from compiling it.  Maybe you need to identify which compiler and which platform (o/s, and maybe IDE) you are using.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's okay now obviously it works when I call the function upon a variable (type char*) instead of string literal (this is not my fault, the student who made autotests didn't know he had to use variable instead of a literal. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Djule: Now you know why it's crucial to show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Had we seen a string literal being passed to your function, we'd have known instantaneously how to enlighten you about the problem.  Glad it's resolved, but please remember for next time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much. I'm sorry I'm new here. I just made my account like an hour ago. Thank you. Greetings.

Comment: @Djule: Once upon a time, we were all new here.  For some of us, longer ago than for others.  There's an art to asking good questions here.  And the MCVE page and the [Ask] pages both help.  But understanding takes some time too.

Comment: For a compact variant of the code, consider: `char *EraseLeadingWhiteSpace(char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str); size_t spc = strspn(str, " \t"); memmove(str, str + spc, len + 1 - spc); return str; }`.  The one downside is that it scans the string 2+ times — once for `strlen()`, once for `memmove()`, and a partial scan for `strspn()` (unless the whole string is white space — then it is a third full scan).  You can add newlines etc to the list of characters to skip if you desire.

Comment: On second thoughts: the `EraseLeadingWhiteSpace()` function above scans the string twice.  The `strlen()` scans it once; the `strspn()` scans the first part, and the `memmove()` scans the rest in a second pass, regardless of content.

Comment: And one other option: you could simply return a pointer to the first non-white space character and use that from here onwards: `char *SkipLeadingWhiteSpace(char *str) { return str + strspn(str, " \t"); }` with no copying.  This has the additional merit of working with character string literals.  You could make it take and return `const char *` too since it does not modify the string it is passed.